# Showing two definitions of the Quaternion Algebra are the same

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quaternions

For $q=z+jw$ where $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$, I'm given a map $M:\mathbb{C}^2\rightarrow M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{C})$ given by $$M(q)=\begin{pmatrix}
z & \overline{w} \\
-w & \overline{z} \end{pmatrix}$$

and I want to show that $M(q_1q_2)=M(q_1)M(q_2)$. I can't seem to avoid doing a long computation, which is difficult to carry out. Is there a faster way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No long computation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1 & \bar{w}_1 \\
-w_1 & \bar{z}_1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
z_2 & \bar{w}_2 \\
-w_2 & \bar{z}_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1z_2-\bar{w}_1w_2 & z_1\bar{w}_2+\bar{w}_1\bar{z}_2\\
-(z_2w_1+\bar{z}_1w_2) & \bar{z}_1\bar{z}_2-w_1\bar{w}_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now observe that, for real $\alpha$ and $\beta$,
$$
j(\alpha+i\beta)=j\alpha+ji\beta=j\alpha-ij\beta=(\alpha-i\beta)j
$$
so $jw=\bar{w}j$, for $w\in\mathbb{C}$. Then
\begin{align}
(z_1+jw_1)(z_2+jw_2)
&=z_1z_2+jw_1z_2+z_1jw_2+jw_1jw_2\\
&=z_1z_2+jw_1z_2+j\bar{z}_1w_2+j^2\bar{w}_1w_2\\
&=(z_1z_2-\bar{w}_1w_2)+j(z_2w_1+\bar{z}_1w_2)
\end{align}